# sql - Is it possible to add foreign key to table which references to id colum on the same table

Tags: php, mysql, account, user-accounts

I have user account system which needs sub-account system. So there is the "main account" and accounts that can acces the main account data. I was thinking of users table where is field "subaccount" true or false. And then according to "parent-account" field open data from account id that the "parent-account" references to.

How do you feel about this?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id
if("SUBACCOUNT" exists){
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= :parentaccount
   echo parentaccounddata
   $_session['parentaccount'] = false; //restrict certain features
}
```

Comment: So you have two types of accounts, main accounts for admins and sub accounts for users. A sub account is connected to one main account and you want to restrict permissions if the account of the logged-in person is a sub account and not a main account. Did I understand that right?

Comment: Yes. I want that sub account can see and get into the main account data. (and after that shut off certain features)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a table reference its own primary key via foreign key constraint (at least it is in MySQL, but I see no reason why other SQL based databases wouldn't allow it).

However I'd like to propose alternative solution. Adding new table which will connect accounts:

```
CREATE TABLE `accountConnection` (
  `accountId` int NOT NULL,
  `subAccountId` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accountId`, `subAccountId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkAccountId` FOREIGN KEY (`accountId`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fkSubAccountId` FOREIGN KEY (`subAccountId`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used MySQL for the example. This way you allow many to many relationship between accounts and sub-accounts, which I'm not sure if you need from your question, but is very flexible solution, even if you don't need it right now, should you ever need to change your system to allow for it

Comment: The greatest strength of this solution that every account can be "a sub-account" to many other accounts and at the same time it can have many other accounts as "sub-accounts". In case of account with id 1 having sub-accounts with ids 3, 5, 10 you'd have 3 rows in the connection table:
{accountId: 1  subAccountId: 3}, {accountId: 1  subAccountId: 5}, {accountId: 1  subAccountId: 10}
Every new account/sub-account relationship adds a row into a connection table

Comment: Furthermore you can limit every account to having just one supper-account (account to which it is a sub-account) by adding constraint unique on `subAccountId` column of the `accountConnection`table. And if, later you decide to remove that restirction, it is as simple as removing a constraint. You'd have no need to significantly change any tables

Answer (score 0):

If every account has only one parent it is a quite straight forward implementation. You want to create a user table with an `id` and a `parent` column. If the account is a main account you can just set the `parent` column to NULL. If it is a sub account you can set it to the `id`.

**Table Creation**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- other parameters like name, ip, ...
    `parent` int(11) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`parent`) REFERENCES `accounts`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

To check if it is a main account or not just check if the parent column is set to NULL or not.